# How to iterate through a tree and print notes at a certain depth in Java?

Tags: java, tree

Given a depth (of a tree) as a command line argument, how could you implement an iteration through the tree and stop at that depth, and then print the nodes ONLY at that depth in order?

Tree structure:

```
    Root:        A       (Depth)   0
              /     \
           C           B           1
         / | \        / \
        E  D  F      G   H         2
```

Example output:
Depth = 0
Output = A

Depth = 1
Output = B,C

Depth = 2
Output = D,E,F,G,H

The only way to iterate through a tree structure that I am aware of is the while(iterator.hasNext()) loop - however, if I try to print the nodes of the tree within this loop, it will print the nodes at that level AND the nodes preceding it, which is not what I want.

EDIT: Initial code

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     int depth;
     BufferedReader input = null;

     try
     {
      input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
      depth = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

      String currentLine = "";
      TreeSet<String> lineSet;
      lineSet = new TreeSet<String>();
      while((currentLine = input.readLine()) != null)
      {
       lineSet.add(currentLine);   
      }
      Iterator<String> iterator;
      iterator = lineSet.iterator();
      while (iterator.hasNext())
      {
       System.out.println(iterator.next());
      } // while
     } // try
     catch(IOException exception)
     {
      System.err.println(exception);
     } // catch
     finally
     {
      try{ if (input != null) input.close(); }
      catch (IOException exception)
      { System.err.println("Could not close input " + exception); }
      } // finally
     } // main
```

Comment: @axiom Yes, I'll edit the question with the code I've tried so far - the output I'm getting is simply an iteration through all lines from a test file in alphabetical order.

Comment: What does the tree structure look like?

Comment: I'm guessing this is either homework or an interview question. Hint: Use a Deque to save the nodes at the given level instead of just printing them out.

Comment: @pcalcao It's an interview question - could you explain to me what a Deque is please?

Comment: A Deque is an implementation of a DoubleEndedQueue, it exists in Java collections, look it up. If you have no further requirements, just printing them, an ArrayList or something like that is fine. Basic idea is that you add them to another structure, then print it.

Comment: Ok, thank you - I think my problem is trying to implement it with a TreeSet, I'll try it with a Deque instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically you traverse the tree in breadth first order until you hit the depth you want. Then start printing out the nodes or collect them into a list/set and print that one out later.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to do a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).
However, I'm afraid you cannot get enough of the internals of `TreeSet` or any other data structure from the JDK.

Hence, you need to implement your own tree data structure (or use a third-party library).

Comment: Is that why you can only implement traversal of a non-ordered, non-binary tree using e.g. a LinkedList or a Queue?

Comment: @user2112464 I'm not sure I understand your last comment. A `LinkedList` or a `Queue` is *not* a tree. What I'm saying is just that `TreeSet` is a high level object, that provides a high-level iterator. You cannot access the children of a given node, hence, you cannot implement BFS based on it. And I don't think there is another JDK tree-like data structure.

Comment: So in this case, I would need to create a tree structure along the lines of:

`public class Tree<T>private Node<T> root  <br/>
  
  public Tree (T rootData)  <br/>
   root = new Node<T>();  <br/>
   root.data = rootData;  <br/>
   root.children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();  <br/>

 public static class Node<T>  <br/>
  private T data;  <br/>
  private Node<T> parent; <br/>  
  private List<Node<T>> children;<br/>  `

Comment: Yes, except that I don't see the use of class `Tree`. A tree is simply given by its root node.